# Error using changes package

Tags: errors, color, changes

I get an error that I don't understand and I have no idea how to fix this. My minimal working example is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes} 
\definechangesauthor{Me}

\begin{document}

Some \added[id=Me]{more} text.

\end{document}
```

This does not compile on my installation and gives the errors

```
Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \XC@col@rlet was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.6 
    
? 
! Too many }'s.
\\definechangesauthor ...let {Changes@Color#2}{#3}
                                                   
l.6
```

On Overleaf the document compiles without errors, so I think it has to be an issue with my installation.

```
pdflatex --version
```

returns

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
```

if this helps…

Here is the log-file I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.11.6)  23 NOV 2023 07:48
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**mwe.tex
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/home/dlorenz/texmf/tex/latex/LaTeX/changes.sty
Package: changes 2007/10/10 v0.5.2 changes-Paket

*** changes-Paket 2007/10/10 v0.5.2 ***
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count193
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfcolmk/pdfcolmk.sty
Package: pdfcolmk 2019/11/24 v2.0 Color support for pdfTeX via marks
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty
\UL@box=\box50
\UL@hyphenbox=\box51
\UL@skip=\skip49
\UL@hook=\toks18
\UL@height=\dimen139
\UL@pe=\count194
\UL@pixel=\dimen140
\ULC@box=\box52
Package: ulem 2019/11/18
\ULdepth=\dimen141
)
\c@Changes@AuthorCount=\count195
\c@Changes@iAuthor=\count196
\c@Changes@AddCount=\count197
\c@Changes@DeleteCount=\count198
\c@Changes@ReplaceCount=\count199
)
\c@Changes@AddCountMe=\count266
\c@Changes@DeleteCountMe=\count267
\c@Changes@ReplaceCountMe=\count268

Runaway argument?
{
./mwe.tex:4: Paragraph ended before \XC@col@rlet was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.4 
    
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

./mwe.tex:4: Too many }'s.
\\definechangesauthor ...let {Changes@Color#2}{#3}
                                                   
l.4 
    
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count269
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box53
)
(./mwe.aux)
\openout1 = `mwe.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count270
\scratchdimen=\dimen142
\scratchbox=\box54
\nofMPsegments=\count271
\nofMParguments=\count272
\everyMPshowfont=\toks19
\MPscratchCnt=\count273
\MPscratchDim=\dimen143
\MPnumerator=\count274
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count275
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks20
)

./mwe.tex:7: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Changes@Colorid=Me'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 Some \added[id=Me]{more}
                             text.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.

./mwe.tex:7: LaTeX Error: No counter 'Changes@AddCountid=Me' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 Some \added[id=Me]{more}
                             text.
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

\Changes@OutFile=\write3
\openout3 = `mwe.loc'.

[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./mwe.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1887 strings out of 478287
 28287 string characters out of 5849289
 322217 words of memory out of 5000000
 20118 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469365 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 48i,5n,61p,203b,108s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/t
exlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page, 21627 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: No issues on up to date TeXLive 2023.

Comment: It compiles without error for me on TL2020-2023. Can you provide the log file of your compilation of the MWE?

Comment: The full log is actually not that long, so I am going to attach it. Thanks already for taking the time to look at it!

Comment: Looking at the log myself, I realized that the changes packet was really old. I updated it in my local texmf and now it works. Weird. It was a fresh install of texlive-full on Ubuntu 22.04…

Comment: your local texmf folder takes precedence. It is not a good idea to update packages by hand as you often forget you did so.

Comment: What would be the preferred way to update the package in a consistent way? I guess it is not possible via apt, but I should use tlmgr?

Comment: Note that it is unlikely that there will be any updates of a LaTeX installation gotten from a Linux dist. They change `tlmgr` such that users can only install latex packages through `apt`. If you need the newest you need to manually install upstream TeXLive (tug.org/texlive). It can be updated through its update cycle using `tlmgr`.

Comment: A perhaps safer way if you want to keep using `texlive-full` from apt (which has advantages) in case you need an updated version of a package could be to put the new package version in the directory of the document for which you need it. Then it will be picked up by that document but your next document in a different directory will use the apt version again. This would prevent an old update from interfering with your new documents, and allows apt to update the package system-wide for the next Ubuntu release (which is sufficiently frequent to minimize bugs/missing features for normal use).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was resolved by a package update.